# CS1525 C# Invalid expression term ')' and CS1729 C# 'Vector3' does not contain a constructor that takes 4 arguments

Tags: typescript

Its in this code:

if (e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad1)
{
var npc = World.CreatePed(PedHash.AviSchwartzman, Game.Player.Character.GetOffsetInWorldCoords(new Vector3(0, 5, 0,)));
npc.Weapons.Give(WeaponHash.Crowbar, 1, true, true);
npc.Task.FightAgainst(Game.Player.Character);
}

I don't know what to do

Comment: `new Vector3(0, 5, 0,)` you have an extra comma. `C#` is pretty picky about syntax it assumes you meant to call it with 4 args and fourth arg is nothing, just get rid of the trailing comma and you're good.

Comment: In the future, please use triple backtick (```) to format your code as code it makes it easier to read.